# How when inserting new Flutter widget have Android Studio automatically insert matching closing parenthesis in correct place?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Watching Flutter videos I've seen power users painlessly insert a new Flutter widget deep inside already nested widgets and Android Studio "magically" inserts the closing parenthesis in exactly the right place.

In contrast, I have to manually "hunt" through the closing curly brackets/parenthesis until I discover the correct } insertion point.

Say I want to insert Center( ... ) at the caret below.  What keystrokes to have the closing parenthesis auto-inserted between Image.network and Scaffold closing parenthesis?

[image]

The demos go so fast I can't ascertain what keystroke recipe they are using to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the little light bulb in your screenshot you get a list of suggested actions:

[image]

And there you get to wrap your widget with the most common other widgets.

On the keyboard that would be Alt/Option + Enter in the default Android Studio keymap.